# Why does my for-loop work in the console, but not in my Helper?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, meteor

I am confused at what is going on with my code. 
When I run this (the code below) code snippet in my Chrome console, it successfully runs as designed to. However when It runs in the app, it fails to run as designed.

The intention with this code snippet, is check whether the contents of the `selectedItemIDSet` array, exist in the total number of `TotalOfallIds` array. If it does then its supposed to pop-up a `Yes` else return a `No`

```
 var selectedItemIDSet = Session.get('selectedItemIDSet'); 
 console.log (selectedItemIDSet);
```

The console.log() function above yeilds:

**["GttzCQLzMeqj", "yzML7ZLvkWkjBBvq5", "2HwJhHyjDhDogJK"]**

```
var TotalOfallIds =  buyList.find().fetch().map(function(u) { return u._id; });

console.log (TotalOfallIds);
```

The console.log() function above yeilds:

**EkebEek7KH8mdpNXg,LZJKA8S3wYNwHakzE,ikrbCDuttHrwkEcuv,
yzML7ZLvkWkjBBvq5,e72HwJhHyjDhDogJK,GttzCQLzMeqjJP4Ae,
XzGxS3LDtJ4DrXSdc,FJDhf7mzCxX4CKThe,TaTg6hf3Gok5NsWYp,
NhDXRMnLWpwfAkWzJ,nG9TsoScYGFbEuerr,8CdapJoeSxSScHKFs,
EsjSJfSgatrYTEnDK**

```
 var noOfloops = selectedItemIDSet.length;
 var selectedItemId = this._id;
 var allclicked;

for(var i = 0; i < noOfloops; i++ ) {
var clickedImg = selectedItemIDSet[i];
allclicked = TotalOfallIds.indexOf(clickedImg) > -1; 

console.log("May: " +allclicked);
    if (allclicked == 1 ) {
        alert("Yes! " );
    //  return "selectedItem";
        }
   else {   
    alert("No! ");
    //return "";
    }}
```

The above works just fine in the console, however in my template.helper the for-loop seems to fail to loop (three times) through the `selectedItemIDSet` array, but loops (13 times) through all `TotalOfallIds` properties, also it only seems to check the `GttzCQLzMeqj` property against the `TotalOfallIds`!

This doesnt make any sense to me!

Find below my code as found in my template.helper.

```
'selectedItem' : function () {     

       var selectedItemIDSet = Session.get('selectedItemIDSet');
        var TotalOfallIds =  buyList.find().fetch().map(function(u) { return u._id; });
        var loops = selectedItemIDSet.length;
        var selectedItemId = this._id;      
        var allclicked = true;

    for(var i = 0; i < loops; i++ ) {
    alert("Checking..." + selectedItemIDSet[i]+ " in " +TotalOfallIds);
    var clickedImg = selectedItemIDSet[i];
    allclicked = TotalOfallIds.indexOf(clickedImg) > -1; 

        if (allclicked == 1 ) {
            alert("Yeeeeiiiii! " );
            return "selectedItem";      
            }
       else {   
        alert("Nnoooooo! ");
        return "";
        }


    }

},
```

Sorry about the verbosity!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the helper, did you examine "this._id" to ensure it's what you expect?

Comment: @zim Thanks but, I found out that It had nothing to do with the this._id. I just had to restructure my code. I am adding the resolution in the: "Answer your Question" section.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing the if condition code from the original `if (allclicked == 1 )` to `if (selectedItemId.indexOf(clickedImg) != -1)` . It still doesn't make any sense why it would work in the console but not in code.

So... the full working if condition code is:

```
if (selectedItemId.indexOf(clickedImg) != -1) {

                alert("Yes! " +clickedImg  );

                return "selectedItem";

    }


else {
//          alert("No! ");
     }
```